# Contour Integration Problem for reciprocal of Bessel Function Power

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Hopefully some one can help me with this problem.
I have  to compute
      $$ \oint_C \frac{1}{[J_0(\alpha t)]^n}dt$$

where $C$ is a contour that contains the first zero $\displaystyle{\frac{\lambda_1}{\alpha}}$ of $J_0(\alpha t)$, i.e. we have 
only have one pole of order $n$  inside $C$.

I compute the values for $n=1$  and I use Mathematica to calculate other values. But, I am unable to get a general formula formula for this integral. Any ideas or references will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Best wishes,

P